# Wagtail Admin Images Crash

Tags: django, wagtail

Since I updated my production setup to Wagtail *1.11* I cannot load the admin page for images. Visiting `/admin/images/` results in a 502 error. In my development setup I don't have the same problem

This is the result of a crash of the runner. The memory and CPU usage of the runners gets too high for the server to handle at which point they are killed. (Seen in `top` and restarts are shown in the logs)

This seems to be the same as https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3575, but `Wand` is not used and no GIF images are uploaded to the system so this is not the cause. The following seemingly relevant python packages are used:

```
Django==1.11.3
gunicorn==19.7.1
Pillow==4.2.1
wagtail==1.11.1
Willow==0.4
```

The project is running on a fully updated Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Does anyone have a suggestion of what can fix this bug?

Comment: What version of Wagtail were you on before?

Comment: @gasman I was on version `1.10.1`. I followed all updates since the start of my project in March

Comment: I can't immediately see any changes in 1.11 which would affect the /admin/images page. Is it possible that you upgraded some other package at the same time? My main suspect is Imagemagick / Wand (are you using that...?) - /admin/images potentially has to render a large number of thumbnails, and we've had some reports of high memory usage https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3575 which might be causing the server process to be killed here.

Comment: Your diagnosis seems accurate since the process is killed in the way you describe. I'm however not aware that I'm using these packages. Any tip on which package I should look for on a ubuntu machine?

Comment: `pip freeze | grep Wand` will tell you what version of Wand (if any) you're using.

Comment: I'm not using Wand. The command doesn't output anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing some of the more recent or larger images and reloading the page. The problem could be the result of a corrupt or malicious image.

The easiest way to diagnose if this is the problem is to:

1. Move all images from the `media/original_images` folder to a backup folder.
2. Access the `/admin/images` page. If this was the problem the page should now load again.
3. Note all images that now do not have a thumbnail; these are the pictures crashing the application.
4. Move all picture except for the ones noted back into the `media/original_images` folder.

Except for the picture crashing your system, everything should now work similar to what it did before.